# Errors when running script from home directory

Tags: bash, centos, home

I've noticed weird behaviour while working with [hcat](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog) on CentOS 7. As an example, a simple command to test connection

```
hcat -e "show databases"
```

returns errors while running from home (`~/`) directory, while it is successful when running from any other directory.

`whereis hcat` returns a single location of `/usr/bin/hcat`.

Question: how to debug this?

I'm not experienced much on unix, but I'm guessing that something might be interfering with bash, though `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` seem to be clean. Additionally, it works fine for other users. Also, same behaviour is seen when running with `sudo` rights, so it shouldn't be a permission issue?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @schaiba ``FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException null)``. Also, the usual messages of Hive.Config doesn't appear at start, suggesting that it fails fetching config files before start. I could edit the question with the full trace, but I'm not sure it will be of much use if it's due to missing config?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool but I suspect you have a configuration file in your home that is read by hcat. You cat try to use `strace -e open hcat -e "show databases"` to print what files has been tried to access by a command.

Comment: @Kalavan thanks, really useful tool. Played around with it, but the files accessed were the same in both cases, so I guess the problem is somewhere deeper.